# SELECT funcionario.name WHERE COUNT() > AVG() GROUP BY funcionario

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wont to SELECT funcionario.name WHERE COUNT() > AVG() GROUP BY funcionario

funcionario = Employee

cliente = client

```
SELECT funcionario.nome
 FROM cliente
 INNER JOIN funcionario ON cliente.nr_funcionario = funcionario.nr_funcionario
 WHERE 
 ((SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM cliente
    INNER JOIN funcionario ON cliente.nr_funcionario = funcionario.nr_funcionario
    GROUP BY funcionario.nome) > 
 (SELECT AVG(total)
 FROM
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM cliente
    INNER JOIN funcionario ON cliente.nr_funcionario = funcionario.nr_funcionario
    GROUP BY funcionario.nome)))
 GROUP BY funcionario.nome
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question.

Comment: put some sample date, expected output and also the question :-)

Comment: I ask right on top 
0
down vote
favorite
I wont to SELECT funcionario.name WHERE COUNT() > AVG() GROUP BY funcionario.nome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the sense that you are confused about how to place a constraint on a given *group* in a query.  The `HAVING` keyword is used for this, and can be thought of as doing what the `WHERE` clause does to individual records, except that instead it acts on *groups* of records.  However, using common table expressions we can greatly simplify the query to the following:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT f.nome, COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM cliente c
    INNER JOIN funcionario
        ON c.nr_funcionario = f.nr_funcionario
    GROUP BY f.nome
)
SELECT t.nome
FROM cte t
WHERE t.total > (SELECT AVG(total) FROM cte)
```

Comment: `Not working` doesn't help me or anyone else answer your question.  Post sample data and your expected output please.

Comment: After all, one thing was missing and it's working now. Thx for the code

Comment: I think  AVG(total) will give average of all the data not the average of group wise

Comment: @RameshKharbuja - SELECT funcionario.nome
FROM cliente
INNER JOIN funcionario
    ON cliente.nr_funcionario = funcionario.nr_funcionario
GROUP BY funcionario.nome
HAVING COUNT(*) > (SELECT AVG(total)
 FROM
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM cliente
    INNER JOIN funcionario ON cliente.nr_funcionario = funcionario.nr_funcionario
    GROUP BY funcionario.nome))

Comment: @Luis -I realised both are same

Answer (score 1):

As i dont have actual table to test,
but the use the following concepts you will definitely get right result

```
    declare @average int;
     SELECT @average= AVG(count (*))
     FROM
        FROM cliente
        INNER JOIN funcionario ON cliente.nr_funcionario = funcionario.nr_funcionario
        GROUP BY funcionario.nome


        SELECT funcionario.nome
     FROM cliente
     INNER JOIN funcionario ON cliente.nr_funcionario = funcionario.nr_funcionario 
        GROUP BY funcionario.nome
having count(functionario.nome)>@average
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to use window functions:

```
select nome
from (select f.nome, count(*) AS total,
             avg(count(*) * 1.0) over () as avg_total
      from cliente c join
           funcionario f
           on c.nr_funcionario = f.nr_funcionario
      group by f.nome
     ) fc
where total > avg_total;
```

This should have better performance than a version that references the CTE more than once.

Comment: I agree with your performance argument +1.  That being said, my query might be a bit easier to read and maintain.  This could also be important.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Actually, I find this easier.  But I'm pretty used to window functions and how to use them.